# Spring HeaderHttpSessionStrategy and WebSockets

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-websocket, spring-session

In my current project I have frontend (Single Page Application) on another server than backend. We decided to use Spring Session with `HeaderHttpSessionStrategy` for token based authentication. Last feature that we wanted to add was websockets with `@SendToUser` feature, and there a stairs has appeared.

With current version of SockJS there is no way to add token header to handshake step because of security reasons. I have tried some things with sending token through Stomp headers, but without success.

I have to add a fact, that with `CookieHttpSessionStrategy` (and when frontend is served from same server) there is no problem, because in handshake step browser automatically inject cookie with session id.

Is there another way to Authenticate and bind user to opened websocket on server side?

Comment: The Web Socket support only supports cookie based authentication

Comment: The web Socket support is still using cookie based authentication? or is now posible to do a `HeaderHttpSessionStrategy` with this?

Comment: @DanielHenao as far as I know this is still problematic but there is a project from socket.io creator that allows you to pass your custom headers during handshake https://github.com/socketio/engine.io-client :)